# Change names of headers in list with list of new header names

Tags: arrays, excel, header, vba

I have a project that has dozens of columns and some of the header names need changing whenever a new excel file is generated for the project.

Also the columns are not contiguous and can shift their positions from one excel file to another.

I have googled this and found nothing that does this specifically.

The closest I have come is [this](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/excel-vba/write-values-to-a-header-row/) that maps a array of names to the first n headers:

i.e

```
headerValues = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")

newheaderValues = Array("NewName1", "NewName2", "NewName3")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the headers are in row 1:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim headerValues As Variant
    Dim newheaderValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    headerValues = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
    newheaderValues = Array("NewName1", "NewName2", "NewName3")

    For i = LBound(headerValues) To UBound(headerValues)
        Rows(1).Replace headerValues(i), newheaderValues(i), xlWhole
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is so simple compared to the link? it worked great thanks